# "gatsby develop" can't run After adjusting image data

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I'm very new Gatsbyjs user. Currently I use this template

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms

My nodejs version is v16.13.2

I could "gatsby develop" but I think when I'm adjusting photo data
in "page-data.json" which stored public\page-data\index
I "gatsby develop" won't start

I'm not sure what is cause but I'm sure when I add some image data into
public\img
and changed lines "coffee.png" in "page-data.json" this happened...

Here is error message. Could someone teach me what part should I fix please ?

```
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-netlify is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.3.0 - It requires gatsby@^3.0.0
⠋ open and validate gatsby-configs, load plugins
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could "gatsby develop" but I think when I'm adjusting photo data in
> "page-data.json" which stored public\page-data\index I "gatsby
> develop" won't start

You should never edit manually the content or the code inside the `/public` folder directly. Keep in mind [how Gatsby works](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/): when you run `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`, webpack compiles and bundles everything under `/src` folder to create the `/public` one: this is autogenerated and it is rebuilt when you change anything on your `/src` folder. If you change anything inside the public folder manually without changing the source, it will be lost in the next compilation because the source doesn't includes the changes. So, all changes must be done in the `/src` folder.

In this case, the error is rising because you changed the public folder directly so the references of the assets `page-data.json` have changed.

To change the [`coffee.png`](https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms/blob/master/static/img/coffee.png) image, you need to change the static folder. The [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/) is a "special" folder that is cloned inside the public folder keeping the exact internal structure. As the name suggests, is very useful to use for static assets (the ones that rarely change).

Once you change the `coffe.png` image for your desired one, you just need to change the references of `coffee.png` to the new one (unless they are called the same).

That said, this kind of static change may force you to reload the `gatsby develop` (stop and rerun) process to see the changes. If the image still without changing, clean the cache by running `gatsby clean` before rerunning the `gatsby develop` command.

Comment: Dear @Ferran Buireu Thank you very much! You helped me again. I'm very clear now. Thank you!