# GraphQL error adding chinese charactor in Gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm new Gatsbyjs.
I use this template

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms

I have question about changing gatsby-node.js file and \src\pages\index.md file.

Actually I asked before and Mr.Ferran Buireu helped me. so I could success to change some text and photos.

["gatsby develop" can't run After adjusting image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936916/gatsby-develop-cant-run-after-adjusting-image-data/70937254#70937254)

Currently I'm adjusting around LINE 16 of \src\pages\index.md file
text: > I would like to change this sentence.

```
intro:
  blurbs:
    - image: /img/coffee.png
      text: >
        日本語を入力したい I would like to change this sentence.
```

I use Japanese sentence and Chinese characters. When I save the file then run gatsby develop Many error show up such as below.

There was an error in your GraphQL query:
Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no
subfields.

but I can see http://localhost:8000/ but with this error message.
And sentence are not changing.
[image]

I know there are problem but I tried to deploy at Netlify the sentence are changed.

I searched solution and tried that gatsby-node.js file non changing save(type space save and delete it and save again).

And  restart gatsby develop but it doesn't work.

Could someone teach me solution please?

Comment: Just to know if the issue is related to the character encoding: Have you tried changing the `text` to another English one? Does still working?

Comment: Dear @Ferran Buireu Thank you for helping me. I didn't gatsby clean. Sorry! Now the project run fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I did gatsby clean command then Everyting fine.