# Determining the cause and debugging a Gatsby bundle build error

Tags: gatsby

I please have the following error during a Gatsby npm run start or npx gatsby develop on Ubuntu :

```
⠼ Building development bundle
/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'activationValue' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at /node_modules/gatsby-plugin-notifications/gatsby-node.js:47:36
    at /node_modules/node-notifier/lib/utils.js:65:5
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:388:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
```

How can I determine at which plugin it occurs or what is the reason for it ?

Previous to it I have some warnings in some of the plugins but it signals as if it succeeded in building them, might it be the cause or perhaps there is a better method to determine exactly where it occurs ?

I have found some Github issues regarding incompatible plugin versions but with no practical solution to how to find if there is such incompatibility nor how to solve it.

I am using Gatsby 4.19 on Ubuntu 20 and Node 16.

The question :
["gatsby develop" can't run After adjusting image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936916/gatsby-develop-cant-run-after-adjusting-image-data)
Is not related at any way.

Thank you!

Comment: What's `activationValue`? Is something you are using somewhere?

Comment: No - it is please internal inside /node_modules/yoga module, I validated it using grep.